# Ошибка  в web.xml

Tags: servlet, web.xml, java-ee

В структуре web.xml имеется следующий код.

```
<servlet>
        <servlet-name>MyServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>MyServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>MyServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/Start.jsp</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>MyServlet2</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/serv2</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
        <welcome-file-list>
            <welcome-file>Start.jsp</welcome-file>
        </welcome-file-list>
```

При запуске сервера выводится ошибка
Server tomcat7 failed to start.
Причина в маппинге, если запускать сервер без второго определения servlet-mapping, то все в порядке.

Comment: Просто догадка: вот так пробовали?  

    <url-pattern>/serv2/Start.jsp</url-pattern>

Comment: Нет, проблема в том, что для маппинга с сервлетом2 не указано описание сервлета.

Answer (score 1):

Для <servlet-mapping> необходимо указывать описание сервлета как это сделано для сервлета MyServlet. Вот корректное описанный web.xml

```
<web-app...     <display-name>WebApp</display-name>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>MyServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>MyServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>MyServlet2</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>MyServlet2</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>MyServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/Start.jsp</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>MyServlet2</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/serv2</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
        <welcome-file-list>
            <welcome-file>Start.jsp</welcome-file>
        </welcome-file-list>
    </web-app>
```